# O que é um SVG?

Tags: html, imagem, svg, processamento-de-imagens

Hoje em dia fala-se em qualidade de imagem e sempre ligado a esse  tipo de afirmação  vez por outra aparece essa sigla misteriosa. Parece ser SVG  algo realmente incrível, dizem que sua imagem não fica distorcida quando ampliada.

Entretanto, nem todos ainda tiveram um primeiro contato sobre seu uso, e usam as mesmas formas de imagem de sempre: PNG,JPG,GIF.

E as vezes o leigo até usa um SVG sem saber que aquilo é um SVG, por exemplo, quando parte de um código vem com uma imagem e ela esta em formato de SVG. 
Logo aos leigos vem a pergunta quando se pensa em construir o tal SVG:
Como se constrói uma figura com essa tecnologia?

E em seguida:

- O que é necessário para o seu desenvolvimento?
- Existe mais de uma forma de implementação?
- Ela é livre ou paga?

Gostaria de um simples exemplo de sua construção.

Comment: Exemplos: http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=svg&type=type-pens

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Obrigado cara!! Esses exemplos parecem muito interessantes!!!

Comment: O SVG vem crescendo após a queda do SWF (flash). É natural não ser conhecido. Outro ponto é que necessita de um suporte mais adequado por parte dos browsers. Um SVG pode ser escrito em códigos no formato plain/text. Para imagens mais complexas é inviável. Nesses casos usa-se softwares de edição de imagens que suportem SVG. Interessante tb que SVG interage com CSS e JS.  O assunto é muito amplo. Não tenho tempo de postar como uma resposta.

Comment: @DanielOmine Obrigado,Para seu comentário podia ser uma resposta. Não há necessidade de uma resposta ampla ,fique a vontade para responder a pergunta,quando tiver algum tempo!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### O que é svg ?

**SVG** é a abreviatura de Scalable Vector Graphics que pode ser traduzido do inglês como gráficos vetoriais escaláveis. Trata-se de uma linguagem XML para descrever de forma vetorial desenhos e gráficos bidimensionais, quer de forma estática, quer dinâmica ou animada.

### Ela é livre ou paga?

Ela é livre!
Este Padrão foi proposto pela W3C em 1999, inspirado em formatos proprietários como VML da Microsoft e PGML da Adobe. 
Em 2001 o SVG ganhou sua primeira versão oficial sendo o svg totalmente open source.

### O que é necessário para o seu desenvolvimento?

Com um bloco de notas você já e capaz de desenvolver svg, porém se você escolher esta forma de implementação irá gastar muito tempo e muita matematica.
quando preciso desenvolver alguma imagem svg eu uso Inkscape, ferramenta Gratuita que permite salvar em svg, mas existem outras como: Adobe Illustrator e Corel Draw. existem também bibliotecas js que facilitam a criação: [RaphaelJS](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

### Exemplo:

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>


<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

**Referencias bibliográficas:**

[Wikipedia svg](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG)

[Tableless - Imagens em alta resolução utilizando SVG](http://tableless.com.br/imagens-em-alta-resolucao-utilizando-svg/)