# Alterar cor marcador li

Tags: html, css, lista

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para alterar a cor da bolinha do marcador `<li>` via CSS.

Pelo oque eu li na internet, até agora só consegui fazer isso usando uma imagem para substituir a bolinha.

Comment: Também dá para fazer usando pseudo-elemento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade [**`list-style-image`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image) e definir uma imagem para substituir as bolinhas:

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kI3v.png')
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Com essa propriedade, é possível até fazer uso de [SVG](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91058/4808) *inline* para criar uma "imagem" com a bolinha (ou outra forma que preferir). Por exemplo:

```css
/**
 * Trocando o atributo "fill" pela cor da sua preferência.
 */

ul {
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><circle fill="blue" cx="7" cy="7" r="2"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Outra alternativa é remover o estilo da lista e criar essas bolinhas com o pseudo elemento [**`:before`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #e74c3c /* cor da bolinha */
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Por convenção se usa dois ':' antes de pseudo-elementos. Assim: `::before` ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Em 2023 fazemos assim.

Sendo o objetivo é unicamente alterar a cor do marcador de um item de lista([`display: list-item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display#item_de_lista), [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary)) use o Pseudo Elemento CSS [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker):

Exemplo 1:

```css
li::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Javascript</li>
  <li>Python</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>C++</li>
  <li>C#</li>
</ul>
```

Exemplo 2:

```css
article {
  display: list-item;
  margin: 20px;
}

span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

article::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <span>Javascript</span>
  <span>Python</span>
  <span>PHP</span>
</article>

<article>
  <span>Java</span>
  <span>C#</span>
  <span>Swift</span>
</article>
```

Exemplo 3:

```css
summary::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Utilize esta tag quando a pergunta se refere a algum recurso, informação ou problema relacionado exclusivamente à linguagem JavaScript (não confundir com Java).</summary>
  JavaScript é uma implementação do ECMAScript, é uma linguagem interpretada, dinamicamente tipada, orientada a objetos e com herança proto-típica. É usada para scripting client-side, todavia pode ser executada em aplicações desktop ou server-side utilizando
  ferramentas como Node.js.
</details>
```

## No Passado.

A pergunta foi formulada em 2016 e até aquele momento as respostas aqui publicadas serviram bem ao propósito.

No mesmo ano a Recomendação [CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4 W3C Working Draft, 7 June 2016](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-css-pseudo-4-20160607/) especificou um novo Pseudo Elemento CSS especifico para selecionar a caixa marcadora de um item da lista, o Pseudo Elemento CSS [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker).

Somente a partir de 2020 que Pseudo Elemento CSS `::marker` começou a ser implementado nos navegadores. Veja [Can I Use CSS :marker pseudo-element](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Amarker%20pseudo).

Hoje em 2023, quando escrevo essa resposta, Pseudo Elemento CSS `::marker` está amplamente difundido entre os principais navegadores modernos. De qualquer forma confira a lista de compatibilidade em desse Pseudo Elemento CSS em [Can I Use CSS :marker pseudo-element](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Amarker%20pseudo).

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o seguinte código no css da LI.
Em color você muda a cor do before, ou seja, a cor da bolinha.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
li:before {
  content: '•';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  color:#00c7ba;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cor da bolinha do marcador herda a cor da lista.
Se voce definir uma cor para a lista e depois subscrever a cor do elemento da lista com alguma tag, cada um vai possuir a sua cor.

```css
ul li{
  color:#f00;
}

ul li span{
  color:#222;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><span>Linha 01</span></li>
   <li><span>Linha 02</span></li>
   <li><span>Linha 03</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode por css na ul:

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url('urlimagem');
}
```

já resolve ;)

Comment: Existem outras opções tbm como li:before e li:after, o pessoal cita algo interessante acima.

Answer (score -2):

ul{
list-style: circle;
color: aliceblue;
}

Answer (score -3):

```css
ul li {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p> nada </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode fazer com o "content: '';"
Assim, você adiciona um conteúdo vazio e personaliza ele na mão.

```css
li {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;

      &::before {
        content: '';
        background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 8px;
        min-width: 8px;

      }
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```